# Ocultar componente no primeiro registro (DBCtrlGrid)

Tags: delphi

Num `TDBCtrlGrid` quero ocultar um componente, na verdade um `TPanel` apenas no primeiro registro do `dataset`.
Tentei no evento `DBCtrlGrid1PaintPanel` verificando quando o **Index = 0** mas quando por exemplo o primeiro registro está selecionado ele acaba mostrando o controle, porque o componente continua *redesenhando* os registros abaixo e altera o TPanel para visível.
Tem como fazer isso? Ocultar ou mostrar um controle dependendo do índice do registro?

Answer (score 0):

Cara fiz um teste aqui e consegui ocultar um componente do seguinte modo

```
procedure TFo_Cadastro_Generico.DBGrid1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   Me_Busca.Visible:=  Qy_Principal.RecNo <> 1;
end;
```

No evento dagrid keyup eu verifico se o numero do registro atual é diferente de 1 (primeiro) se for deixa o maskedit busca visível, se for o primeiro deixa o maskedit busca invisível.

Espero ter compreendido sua pergunta corretamente :) . E espero ter sido claro em meu exemplo também :)

Qualquer duvida é só falar.

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa, mas acho que vc não entendeu corretamente. Repare que não é um `DBGrid`, mas sim um `DBCtrlGrid`. Apesar de serem controles relativamente parecidos, os eventos e lógica para controle dos mesmos são diferentes.

Comment: Boa noite Andrey.. Realmente, na ânsia de ajudar não reparei que o objeto era o DBCtrlGrid.  Já o utilizei algumas vezes.. Realmente não vi um meio de fazer o que tu necessita. desculpe e abraços

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o evento AfterScroll do DataSet para tornar o Painel Visível ou não, seria Mais ou menos assim:

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.ClientDataSet1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Panel1.Visible:= ClientDataSet1.RecNo >1;
end;
```

Então dessa forma toda vez que o primeiro registro for selecionado no DBControlGrid o Painel não será visivel.

Comment: Não funciona amigo, acontece o mesmo, porque os registros abaixo do primeiro tornam visível o panel do primeiro registro. Não sei se faz diferença, vou testar depois, mas o panel está `Align = alTop;`